# Mutable Array Remove all objects Crash Exe Bad Access

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, exe

I am creating a database using sqlite and have all my methods written for inserting, reading, deleting etc.

When i read the database the first time my read method works fine, clearing the array using removeallobjects.

When it is called the second time it crashes the app with the 'exe bad acces's on the [array removeallobjects];

From my experience this is because it is already been released, but i cant find or see where and why this is happening. I can add to the array fine as long as i comment out the calling of the read method. It also works commenting out the remove all objects so its this its having an issue with.

I have written another app in the past that has had no issue and the code is pretty much identical. Is there a way to see if its being released or is this possibly an issue with xCode4?

Any help would be great as i cant dev any further..

Thank Dan

Comment: There isnt any. All i get is bad exe... This error only occurs in the second time of running it. Also i have another app which i have used to base this new app on that works perfect. The only difference is the number of rows in the table

Comment: Fixed. My class which stored data before saving it had a super dealloc before each NSSrting. Moved to the end and job done! Thanks anyhow guys

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Zombie-Instrument (Profiling), that shows you exactly where you access an already deallocated object and when it has been released/retained since its creation

Comment: I have tried Zombie and not sure i should be looking at exactly. Althou when press the button to run the remove it doesnt crash....

Comment: After playing around i am pretty sure its stil alive

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if it is released or not before removing objects.

Comment: i cant see where it is releasing it. if i search the code for the array name nothing shows up.